# Excel Sumifs - multiple column criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to SUMIF multiple columns based on multiple column criteria. I need to get a sum of all the years "2021, 2022, 2023" based on if "Location = Same Location", "Type = Type 1", and "Price >= 70000". And put that total into a column. This should total ALL years that match all criteria.

I have tried several formulas but so far nothing even comes close. I turn to the experts here.

Excel Sheet:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **State** | **Location** | **Type** | **Price** | **2021** | **2022** | **2023** |
| Alabama | Location 1 | Type 1 | 60000-65000 | 1 | 5 | 7 |
| Alabama | Location 1 | Type 1 | 70000-95000 | 3 | 2 | 8 |
| Alabama | Location 1 | Type 2 | 70000-105000 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| Alabama | Location 1 | Type 2 | 90000-125000 | 6 | 5 | 1 |
| Alaska | Location 2 | Type 1 | 60000-65000 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
| Alaska | Location 2 | Type 1 | 70000-85000 | 6 | 7 | 10 |
| Alaska | Location 2 | Type 2 | 70000-105000 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
| Alaska | Location 2 | Type 2 | 80000-115000 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
| Alaska | Location 2 | Type 2 | 90000-125000 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
| California | Location 3 | Type 1 | 60000-65000 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| California | Location 3 | Type 2 | 70000-105000 | 4 | 3 | 6 |
| California | Location 3 | Type 2 | 80000-125000 | 2 | 1 | 5 |
| Nevada | Location 4 | Type 1 | 60000-65000 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| Nevada | Location 4 | Type 1 | 70000-105000 | 7 | 3 | 8 |
| Nevada | Location 4 | Type 2 | 70000-105000 | 2 | 2 | 5 |
| Nevada | Location 4 | Type 2 | 80000-125000 | 3 | 9 | 1 |

Is there anymore I should add to help?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the `SUMIFS()` formula you tried.

Comment: Here is one I was trying:
=SUMIFS(E:G,B4,"*"&"X2"&"*",C:C,"Type 1")

It's not correct, and excel formulas are foreign to me. At least when they get complicated.

The X2 column was a LOOKUP COLUMN, basically just a copy of the B column so I could try to do a compare between the 2. The goal is not to grab ALL locations, only the locations that match together, Location 1 = Location 1, etc.

If this makes any sense.

And my expected output is to be E+F+G  , PER LOCATION , = TOTAL

Comment: you cannot do three columns together like that use three different SUMIFS and sum them: `=SUMIFS(E:E,B:B,B2,C:C,"Type 1")+SUMIFS(F:F,B:B,B2,C:C,"Type 1")+SUMIFS(G:G,B:B,B2,C:C,"Type 1")`

Comment: @ScottCraner Sir, has given you the perfect suggestion, why `SUMIFS()` not working and how you need to use it, also you can use `SUMPRODUCT()` here, `=SUMPRODUCT(("Location 1"=B2:B17)*("Type 1"=C2:C17)*(--TEXTBEFORE(D2:D17,"-")>=7*10^4)*E2:G17)`

Answer (score 1):

Using your data I had to do some adjustments. Since it is not possible to lump sum three columns in one `SUMIF` (like what Scott Craner just said) we have to go column by column.

Now if we use the formula `=SUMIFS(E2:E17, $C$2:$C$17,"Type 1", D2:D17, ">=60000")` we will end up with 0 because the data in Column D is formatted as a range. A recommendation would be to have a column for low range and another for high range then you can filter from there.

Kinda like `=SUMIFS(F2:F17, $C$2:$C$17,"Type 1")` which is the basic SUMIF that will result you 24 based on your data.

So the recommendation is to break up your values into separate smaller column-based sets and then do a `SUMIF` from each column, after that you can combine those into a `SUM` for final tally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want for an output, as you don't show anything, and it's not clear as to what the extent of your variations might be, but if you have Microsoft 365, the following single formula will filter your data according to your specifications, and then output the totals for the years.

Starting with your initial table which I named `Sale`:
[image]

And with your criteria:
[image]

Using this formula in some cell:
*Note that in the below formula `Min` represents the number `70000` and `Type` represents the string `Type 1`.  These can be stored in Named Ranges, or substituted directly in the formula to obtain the results. Having them in Named Ranges allows for some flexibility in varying the filters*

```
=LET(
    l, UNIQUE(Sale[Location]),
    low, --BYROW(
        Sale[Price],
        LAMBDA(arr, INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(arr, "-"), 1))
    ),
    high, --BYROW(
        Sale[Price],
        LAMBDA(arr, INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(arr, "-"), 2))
    ),
    tf, (low >= Min) + (Min <= high),
    f, FILTER(Sale, tf * (Sale[Type] = Type)),
    tot, BYROW(CHOOSECOLS(f, -1, -2, -3), LAMBDA(arr, SUM(arr))),
    data, HSTACK(DROP(f, , -3), tot),
    gt, MAKEARRAY(
        1,
        5,
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            CHOOSE(
                c,
                "Grand Total",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                SUM(CHOOSECOLS(data, -1))
            )
        )
    ),
    VSTACK(HSTACK(DROP(Sale[#Headers], , -3), "Totals"), data, gt)
)
```

will => the following result:
[image]

Comment: Solutions like this are always appreciated and accepted. Literally helps to learn! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems the desired outcome can be presented at least in a couple ways.

- **Easy way**:

  - Step1: Transform Price column (character) into (numeric).
    Given the condition (Price >=70000), take the lower bound for each range
  - Step2: Use If() to detail all the conditions, not to set any condition for Location as all is desired.
  - Step3: The Total is based on all conditions.
  - Step4: To know each location, use filter or Pivot Table

[Excel Worksheet]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXmMg.png

- **Laborious way**

  - Step1: same as before
  - Step2: Add columns (based off on Locations) . Then same as before

[Excel Worksheet]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEeIt.png

**Formulas:**

- **Easy Way**:

  - **Price_interim**: =LEFT(D2,5), where D2 is the original Price
  - **Price_final**: =H2*1, where H2 is Price_interm
  - **Total**: =IF(B2="Location 1",IF(C2="Type 1",IF(OR(I2>70000,I2=70000),SUM(E2:G2),"NA")))
- **Laborious way**

  - **Total Location(1)**: =IF(B2="Location 1",IF(C2="Type 1",IF(OR(I2>70000,I2=70000),SUM(E2:G2),"")))
  - **Total Location(2)**: =IF(B2="Location 2",IF(C2="Type 1",IF(OR(I2>70000,I2=70000),SUM(E2:G2),"")))